# How do I send an array of object in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, jstl

I have the following method in servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAll());

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Category.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```

and when i call jsp page i want to get all categories from get but it's simply does not call get method

here is my jsp

```
<body>
<% List<CategoryDTO> categoryList=new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>(); 
categoryList=(ArrayList<CategoryDTO>)request.getAttribute("categories");
%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.name}</td>

  </tr>
</c:forEach
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you try changing `${categoryList}` to `${categories}`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I've changed ..nothing happen .. but it does not fire the get method

Comment: Can you also check whether `categoryService.getAll()` returns any record(s)?

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare list in jsp, just try like this ,

```
<body>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:forEach items="${categories}" var="element"> //change here categories not categotyList
  <tr>
    <td>${element.name}</td>

  </tr>
</c:forEach
```